# C++: Calling a Recursive function of an Abstact function

Tags: c++, abstract

I would like to know how to call a recursive function of an abstract class using C++.

```
    //A.h
        class A {
    public: 
    virtual void some() = 0 ; 

    };

    //B.h
       #include "A.h"
    class B : public A {
    public:
     void some() ; 

    };

    // B.cpp


    void B::some(){
  system("pause"); 
 } ; 


    //C.h
  #include "B.h" 
class C : public B  {
public:
static void callF() ; 

};

    // C.cpp

    void C::callF(){ 
    some();
```

} ;

I have edited the code. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

In A and B the function should be either public or protected.

Comment: thanks , i have made those methods public now. but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just use `somefunction()` inside the body of `C::callingF()` eg like

```
void C::callingF() 
{
   if (somecondition) 
     somefunction();
}
```

and you could use `ptr->somefunction()` if `ptr` is a pointer to some `C` or `B` i.e. a pointer to some `A`

But please, take hours to read a good book about the C++ programming language. We cannot explain it here in a few minutes. A book explains better...